# firebase google authentication with token

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, firebase-authentication, jwt

I am new to reactjs world
I am working on one small project for where reactjs and firebase connectivity is needed
I am working on firebase google authentication, small part I have implemented as shown below,

**LoginPage.js**

```
import { auth,provider } from '../firebase'

const loginMethod=()=>{
        auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then((result)=>{
            dispatch(
                setVariableInfo({
                    var1:result.user.displayName,
                    var2:result.user.email,
                    var3:result.user.photoURL
                })
            )
        })
    }
```

using above code i can see one pop is coming when i hit the url to browser and i can successfully authenticate with google account. But when i try to refresh the url it again popup and asked me to authenticate with google account.

How to achieve same thing what youtube or gmail has implemented?? how we can authenticate with a user using token ??

please help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

On page refresh plz check do user logged in or Not

```
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const auth = getAuth();
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, 
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // ...
  }
});
```